# How does Worklight Clustering work in WAS Liberty Core?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty

All,

I am trying to set up the Worklight cluster using WAS Liberty Core. As of now, i have installed two Worklight servers on two different servers on its own Liberty Core. And I have configured the WL to point to the same DB setup for both WL installations.

As we know that Liberty Core does not come with any network deployment features, how are the Liberty nodes clustered? Or we dont need to do this step at all?

Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clustered? The servers don't "know" about each other. At the WebSphere Liberty level you have two independent Application Servers that you administer separately. You will need to front those servers with some kind of "sprayer" so that requests are sent to those servers. You could use IBM HTTP Server (free, extended Apache) and deploy the [WebSphere plugin](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_admin_webserver_plugin.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-3-6&lang=en).

Your applications need to target the sprayer (eg. the HTTP Server) rather than either of the individual Liberty servers.

Your Worklight WAR file is deployed to both servers and shares the common database and hence in effect is clustered - you only need to perform admin actions such as deploying an adapter once, that updates the shared database.